# Confusing domain of simple $f(x, y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, solution-verification

I'm not sure if my way of solving this task is correct. Perhaps I've done some "math-grammar" mistakes, or some calculating errors? Especially speaking of assumptions 2. Would anyone double-check my calculations?

**Given function** $f(x,y) = \sqrt{\pi-3\arcsin\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{3}}} + \ln(1-y^2-x^2)$ **find the domain of this function.**

---

**Assumption 1:**
$$-1 \leq \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{3}} \leq 1$$
$$-\sqrt{3} \leq x+y \leq \sqrt{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow -\sqrt{3} -x\leq y \quad \land \quad y \leq -x + \sqrt{3}$$
$$\Longrightarrow  y \geq -x -\sqrt{3} \leq \quad \land \quad y \leq -x + \sqrt{3}$$

---

**Assumption 2:**
$$\pi - 3\arcsin{\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{3}}} \geq 0$$
$$- 3\arcsin{\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{3}}} \geq -\pi$$
$$3\arcsin{\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{3}}} \leq \pi$$
$$\arcsin{\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{3}}} \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$$
$$\Rightarrow \sin{\frac{\pi}{3}} \leq \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \leq \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\frac{3}{2} \leq x+y$$
$$y \geq -x + \frac{3}{2}$$

---

**Assumption 3:**
$$1 - y^2 - x^2 > 0$$
$$- y^2 - x^2 > - 1$$
$$y^2 + x^2 < 1$$

---

**Hence:**
$$\Longrightarrow D = \Bigg( (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : (y^2 + x^2 < 1), (y \geq - x + \frac{3}{2} ), (y \leq -x + \sqrt{3}) \Bigg) $$

Is this a good enough answer? Do you see some obvious mistakes? Thanks.

Comment: Your approach is right. The assumption 3 gives an open circle. Note that if A3 holds, then A1 holds as well (the circle lies in the stripe). It seems to me there is a mistake in A2. The sine is increasing. Anyway, this assumption is again  included in A3.